# c++: Error: No instance of overloaded function using std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

//Global variable
std::mutex mu; //declare a mutex
std::map<std::string, int> threadIDs;

void run(int id) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> map_locker(mu); 
    threadIDs.insert(std::make_pair(std::this_thread::get_id(), id));
    map_locker.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i] = std::thread(run, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i].join();
    }
    return 0;    
}//end of the code
```

Hello, I am trying to execute 5 thread running the `void run()` function and save thread id and `int` value using `std::map`. However I get red underline underneath the '.' in `threadIDs.insert(std::make_pair(std::this_thread::get_id(), id));` line saying no instance of overloaded function...
I guess the error occurs because `std::map` wants a `string` and an `int` inside but I am trying to put `std::this_thread::get_id()` in the string place. How can I put the thread identity inside the `std::map`?

Comment: DAN - welcome to SO. While you may be knew to C++ and to programming in general, it's never to early to start learning to read documentation and to research compiler errors before asking others. You will learn so much more through your own research. I feel like you could have done just a little bit more research and solved this problem yourself, since you already seemed to have figured out that the problem was that your map key is a string. You were just a step or two away and for that reason I am am down voting your question http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::this_thread::get_id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) returns `std::thread::id`, which is not the same as `std::string`. Your map should store `std::thread::id` as its key type.